# How to get root by recursive oracle query in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I'm a little curious, is there a way to get result of connect by sql query like root Entity with already mapped descendants.
So if I'm insert in base something like this:

```
insert into table test (id, parent_id, some_text) values
(1, null, 'a'),
(2, 1, 'b'),
(3, 1, 'c'),
(4, 2, 'd');
```

then by sql query

```
select *
from test t
start with t.id = 1
connect by prior t.id = t.parent_id
order siblings by t.some_text
```

I will get

```
id | parent_id | some_text
 1        null           a
 2           1           b
 4           2           d
 3           1           c
```

and by entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private BigInteger id;

    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    private BigInteger parent_id;

    @Column(name = "some_text")
    private String someText;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<Test> descendants;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Test parent;
    // getters and setters
}
```

it will back to me as list of Test. It possible to get root and full tree by recursive function, but it will get new query on iteration (it will very long if I have a big tree).
So is there a possible good way to get root of this tree with already mapped descendants by this query (maybe extend/implement some class/interface which will process mapping from jdbc to entity)?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` unary operator.
See [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm)

```
select t.*, connect_by_root id
from test t
start with t.id = 1
connect by prior t.id = t.parent_id
order siblings by t.some_text
```

BTW: this has nothing to do with Hibernace. This is purely Oracle specific solution.

Comment: thx for you answer but Hibernate it's the main point, and I will try to use your query with addRoot() if it will work i tell here.